# How to choose the most voted category from multiple columns in R

Tags: r, voting, categorical

I have a classification problem I need to solve using R, but to be sincere I have no clue on how to do it.

I have a table (see below) where different samples are classified by three ML models (one per column), and I need to choose the "most voted" category for each case and write it to a new column.

Current table

[image]

Desired Output

[image]

I have been reading about categorical variables in R, but anything seem to fit my specific needs.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

JL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you ask a question. Please see the relevant thread, and in the future offer the data in the form shown below (using `dput()` and copy and paste the result from the console). At any rate here is a base R solution:

```
# Calculate the modal values: mode => character vector
df1$mode <- apply(
  df1[,colnames(df1) != "samples"],
  1,
  function(x){
    head(
      names(
        sort(
          table(x), 
          decreasing = TRUE
        )
      ),
     1
    )
  }
)
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(samples = c("S1", "D4", "S2", "D1", "D2", "S3", 
"D3", "S4"), RFpred = c("Carrier", "Absent", "Helper", "Helper", 
"Carrier", "Absent", "Resistant", "Carrier"), SVMpred = c("Absent", 
"Absent", "Helper", "Helper", "Carrier", "Helper", "Helper", 
"Resistant"), KNNpred = c("Carrier", "Absent", "Carrier", "Helper", 
"Carrier", "Absent", "Helper", "Resistant"), mode = c("Carrier", 
"Absent", "Helper", "Helper", "Carrier", "Absent", "Helper", 
"Resistant")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: First of all I want to apologize for not being able to ask the question correctly.
Apart from that I want to thank you for your swift and precise answer.
Best regards

Comment: @JLLavin no worries, glad it answered your question and you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Tidyverse Approach:**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mode_char <- function(x) {
    ux <- unique(na.omit(x))
    ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

df %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(
        Vote = mode_char(c_across(RFpred:KNNpred))
    )

#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   samples RFpred    SVMpred   KNNpred   Vote     
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
#> 1 S1      Carrier   Absent    Carrier   Carrier  
#> 2 D4      Absent    Absent    Absent    Absent   
#> 3 S2      Helper    Helper    Carrier   Helper   
#> 4 D1      Helper    Helper    Helper    Helper   
#> 5 D2      Carrier   Carrier   Carrier   Carrier  
#> 6 S3      Absent    Helper    Absent    Absent   
#> 7 D3      Resistant Helper    Helper    Helper   
#> 8 S4      Carrier   Resistant Resistant Resistant
```